# Java Bit Operation Issue

Tags: java

I have incoming bits like, 0, 1, 11, 10 etc. Which I store in a string. Then I convert the string to an Int.

Now, suppose Int A = "011" and Int B = "00". Is it possible in java to know, how many bits was there in the string which I have converted to the Int. Thanks.

Comment: In Java, `int` has size 4 bytes = 32 bits.  Bam, there you go! As a more serious answer, if you have them stored as integers already, you can use a loop and bit-shifting, keeping track of the last `1` you find, because what you're actually looking for is the minimum number of bits to represent that number, right?

Comment: Then look at Adam's answer below, and modify it.  It's not exactly the code you want, it only count's the number of 1's, and you need the number of 0's and 1's, up to the point where the last 1 is reached (you'll read the whole thing, but you'll want to discard the segment from the last 1 to the end.

Comment: @prelic, is it possible to return Int back to bit representation and stored in String and find length.

Comment: Yes it is: `Integer.toBinaryString(int i)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, just test each bit in turn using a mask. For integers there are 32 possible bits.

Luckily java provides this for you:

```
Integer.bitCount(value)
```

If you wanted to do it yourself:

```
int value = Integer.parseInt("1000101010", 2);

int bitCounter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < Integer.SIZE; i++) {
    if (((1 << i) & value) > 0) {
        bitCounter++;
    }
}
System.out.println(value + " has " + bitCounter + " bits");
```

Output

```
554 has 4 bits
```

If alternatively you wanted the "length", i.e. the number of 0s or 1s...

Convert to string and find length

```
System.out.println(Integer.toString(value, 2).length());
```

Use some knowledge of maths to take the base(2) log of the value.

```
double valueUnsigned;
if (value < 0) {
    valueUnsigned = (value & 0x7FFFFFF) + 0x80000000l;
} else {
    valueUnsigned = value;
}
System.out.println("Maths solution " + Math.floor(1d + Math.log(valueUnsigned) / Math.log(2)));
```

Comment: Are you sure he wants only the number of `1` bits? Why not just the minimum number of bits needed to represent the number?

Comment: @prelic You're right, the question is not clear. I've added alternative solutions to count 0s and 1s.

Comment: @Adam - You're right, it just as easily could have been yours, I just thought the test case `00` was weird.  Now the question is, does your code output `32` for all inputs because of the whole `int` being 4 bytes in java? Or does it actually cut off the leading `0`s? Either way, now I like your answer.  +1

Comment: The manual bit count works correctly, so does the string solution.  The math solution fails with NaN as 0xffffffff when converted to a double is negative because of the leftmost sign-bit.

Comment: @prelic Fixed the maths solution by "unsigning" the int into a double.